# If $\frac{3\pi}{4} < x < \pi$ then $\sqrt{\csc^2 x + 2 \cot x}$ is =?

Tags: trigonometry

Q: If $\frac{3\pi}{4} < x < \pi$ then $\sqrt{\csc^2 x + 2 \cot x}$ is equal to what?

A: $\sqrt{ \csc^2 x + 2 \cot x}$
= $\sqrt{1 + \cot^{2} x + 2 \cot x}$
= $\sqrt{(1 + \cot x)^{2}}$
= $\pm (1 + \cot x)$

How do I move from here? The given answer is $- 1 - cotx$. From the inequality all I can conclude is $-1-cotx<0$. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

$$1+\cot x=\dfrac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin x}$$

Clearly $\sin x>0$ here

Now $f(x)=\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\dfrac\pi4\right)$$

and $\dfrac{3\pi}4+\dfrac\pi4<x+\dfrac\pi4<\pi+\dfrac\pi4$

So, $f(x)<0$

Comment: Understood! Thanks!